# Xfce desktop files and folders not showing

Tags: 22.04, xfce

Im using ubuntu 22 and for some reason the xubuntu/xfce sessions have started to fail to display the files and folders. The taskbar/appbar is there and works but the rest of the screen is just the wallpaper and no icon or anything. Even right click doesnt work.

I've tried various suggestions, like cleaning the xfce folder under .cache, but none seems to work. When I do the

```
xfdesktop --reload
```

it does seem to restore the stuff but the command doesnt finish, and closing the terminal or killing it created weird effects like window border ghosts etc.

Ubnity, wayland and other desktop types work fine.

[image]

Comment: I caouldnt take screenshot of the login screen but ther is Ubuntu (with Waylabd) and a Unity in the list of available session types. I've edited the question and added list of available desktops.

Comment: It must be a problem with the (c0nfiguration?) Thunar file manager. This application is what provides desktop icons in Xubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into the same, the solution that worked was to delete the `~/.cache/sessions` folder and relogin.